# grpc : CANCELLED: cancelled before receiving half close

Tags: streaming, grpc, grpc-java

I'm doing streaming from client to server. Many times I'm receiving this error on the server:

```
CANCELLED: cancelled before receiving half close
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: cancelled before receiving half close
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:517) ~[grpc-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onCancel(ServerCalls.java:272) ~[grpc-stub-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closed(ServerCallImpl.java:293) [grpc-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1Closed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:737) [grpc-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) [grpc-core-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Jul 20 2018 04:56:28.441 PM [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler:86 - [id: 0xae106a63, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 - R:/127.0.0.1:40808] OUTBOUND RST_STREAM: streamId=7 errorCode=5
Jul 20 2018 04:56:28.451 PM [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler:86 - [id: 0xae106a63, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 - R:/127.0.0.1:40808] INBOUND DATA: streamId=7 padding=0 endStream=false length=52 bytes=000000002f3a2d0801180120b96028aa1230c3c8013a055452414345420254344a0968656164646c696e655207766973686e7573
Jul 20 2018 04:56:28.453 PM [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler:86 - [id: 0xae106a63, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 - R:/127.0.0.1:40808] OUTBOUND RST_STREAM: streamId=7 errorCode=5
Jul 20 2018 04:56:28.770 PM [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler:86 - [id: 0xae106a63, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 - R:/127.0.0.1:40808] OUTBOUND GO_AWAY: lastStreamId=7 errorCode=2 length=24 bytes=436f6e6e656374696f6e2072657365742062792070656572
Jul 20 2018 04:56:28.773 PM [grpc-default-worker-ELG-3-2] DEBUG i.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler:86 - [id: 0xae106a63, L:/127.0.0.1:9090 ! R:/127.0.0.1:40808] Sending GOAWAY failed: lastStreamId '7', errorCode '2', debugData 'Connection reset by peer'. Forcing shutdown of the connection.
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:418) ~[netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:934) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:360) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:901) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1376) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:768) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:749) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.onError(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:619) [netty-codec-http2-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.grpc.netty.AbstractNettyHandler.exceptionCaught(AbstractNettyHandler.java:81) [grpc-netty-1.12.0.jar:1.12.0]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:285) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:264) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:256) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.exceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1381) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:285) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:264) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireExceptionCaught(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:933) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.handleReadException(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:112) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:157) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459) [netty-transport-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.22.Final.jar:4.1.22.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

May I know why? I'm not shutting down grpc. The GRPC doesn't shutdown after this error. The error is also not consistently occurring.

Comment: It looks like the client hung up on the server, or a router in the network killed the connection. What networking environment are you testing this in?

Comment: It's on local. Both client and server.

Comment: It's still possible for the client to hang up on the server. That'd happen if the process exited before gracefully shutting down, for example.